# Complete financial statement as the part of scholarship application

Tags: application, funding

I'm applying for a scholarship whose application consists of a financial statement, in which I have to breakdown my income and expenditure to show how I manage my money. As the scholarship aims to help me paying for my living expense, I wonder if I should include it in my statement, i.e. assuming that I am awarded the scholarship and present how I should use it.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. Correct me of I am wrong: you are applying for a scholarship and (as part of the application) they ask you how you plan to spend the money, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. They ask me to list my sources of income (e.g. load, earning, parents's contribution...) and describe my spending (e.g. rent, food, bills...)

Comment: If they don't explicitly tell you to include the scholarship money in your spending statement, then don't include it.

Comment: @ff524 Can you please turn this into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** They are asking about your *current* financial situation, as ff524 implied in a comment.

What is required in this situation is a relatively detailed budget listing current sources of income, and current spending. Since you are applying for the scholarship, no one will be surprised if this budget reveals a gap between the income and the projected expenditure--this is your financial need, and the whole purpose of applying for the scholarship is to have the funds needed to 'fill in the gap'.